# PhonegapBuild: How to load CSS and JS files before the splash screen dissapears?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using the Phonegap Build service (From Dreamweaver CS6) and I've been working with this template: http://themeforest.net/item/tiger-jquery-mobile-web-template-web-app/3018322 which includes a lot of js and css files. The problem is that when the splash screen dissapears, the application hasn't loaded all the js and css files needed to display the application correctly, and some features (which work on Android) like the gallery slideshow doesn't work. Also, when I start the Android application, it looks like a web page without css for a while, but it displays the app correctly after few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you following the [phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html) for adding a splash screen?

Assuming you're using the latest version of phonegap (2.8.0), add these lines to your main java class that extends phonegap:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);
```

Then in you app JS:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```

Comment: It was a JQuery error, but I still don't know why it worked on Android devices and it didn't on IOS devices.